# thread exiting error in android

Tags: android

Please help with this error .... In the following code the get info function works correctly but it gives an error saying the thread caught an exception at exiting....  I am trying to use a tab host and the first tab page is the following... In this i show a progress dialog until i get my data and then show it in a list view

```
public class History extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ListView list;

//LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<String> listItems;

//DEFINING STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE DATA OF LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private String resDriver,resPassenger,ID;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> item;
JSONObject jDriver;
//JSONObject jPassenger;

// Make strings for logging
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private final String RESTORE = ", can restore state";
private final String state = "Home Screen taking care of all the tabs";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent loginIntent = getIntent();
    ID = loginIntent.getStringExtra("ID");
    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    Log.i(TAG, "Started view active rides");
    setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    getInfo();
}
```

The function `getInfo` is used to start a thread which shows a dialog box and starts a http request to get some data ...

```
public void getInfo(){
    GetInfoThread checkUpdate = new GetInfoThread();
    checkUpdate.start();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(History.this, "Retrieving Info","Please Wait ...", true);
}

private class GetInfoThread extends Thread
{
    public void run() {
        jDriver = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jDriver.put("ID", ID);
            jDriver.put("task", "GET DATES");

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.i(TAG,"Sending data for the driver rides");
        resDriver = HTTPPoster.sendJson(jDriver,"http://dsadsada"); // Any Server URL

        JSONObject driver;
        try {
            driver = new JSONObject(resDriver);
            Log.i(TAG,"Recieved Driver details");

                    listItems.add(array[0]);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            listItems.add("No driver rides created");
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           dialog.dismiss();
           Log.i(TAG,"hello 123");
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there compulsory to use Thread? If possible just use asyncTask it gives you everything for handlling UI and also you can easily dispaly progress dialog while backgroun work is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what is causing your error but I suspect it has to do with UI changes not running on the actual UI thread. In Android there is a class called [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that will do the threading for you and handle the passing of data between the background thread an the UI thread. I would suggest rewriting your code to utilize the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.

Comment: Could you look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188429/async-task-in-android-not-working